# In python how can I add a key name to the dictionary to dump json

Tags: python, json

1. 

I want to add a key name to the dictionary. Here's the code I use..

```
def save_output(d, outfile):
    with open(outfile, "w") as f:
        json.dump(d, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        f.write("\n")
```

The input dict **'d'** contain ...

```
{
    "coverage": 2.22,
    "mean_coverage": 28.78333,
    "insert_size": 445.76355,
    "pct": 98.13486,
    "sample": "wgs"
}
```

I want the ouput like this with adding a key name **'metrics'** to the dict..

```
{
    "metrics" : {
    "coverage": 2.22,
    "mean_coverage": 28.78,
    "insert_size": 445.76,
    "pct": 98.13,
    "sample": "wgs"
}
```

2. 

Ultimately, I want the final output like this..

```
{
    "sampleid": {
        "id": "SA001"
    },
    "metrics" : {
    "coverage": 2.22,
    "mean_coverage": 28.78,
    "insert_size": 445.76,
    "pct": 98.13,
    "sample": "wgs"
    }
}
```

I'm able to update the first part but unable to add the key name **metrics** to the dict

```
    def save_output(d, outfile):
        with open(outfile, "w") as f:
            tag = {"sampleid" : {"id" : args.sample_id}}
            d.update(tag)
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(d, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
            f.write("\n")

   {
        "sampleid": {
            "id": "SA001"
        },
        "coverage": 2.22,
        "mean_coverage": 28.78,
        "insert_size": 445.76,
        "pct": 98.13,
        "sample": "wgs"
    }
```

Comment: Is `d = {'metrics': d}` what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining tag, you can directly add sampleid and metrics:

```
d = {"sampleid" : {"id" : args.sample_id}, "metrics": d}
```

Output:

```
{'sampleid': {'id': 'SA001'}, 'metrics': {'coverage': 2.22, 'mean_coverage': 28.78333, 'insert_size': 445.76355, 'pct': 98.13486, 'sample': 'wgs'}}
```